# HDMI display suddenly not recognized anymore

Tags: hdmi, external-monitor

I'm having a critical issue on my production machine. Until yesterday, I've been working with my laptop connected to an external display through HDMI.
Now, when I switch the pc on, the display says "no signal".
If I book in Windows7, everything works.

What can I do?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me today, but I got the display back by booting with an older kernel. Obviously not a good fix, but works as a temporary workaround.

Not sure yet what's causing it. Haven't had any kernel update since yesterday, but I did install a java package that pulled in som X11 libraries. No idea yet if it's related, but I'll try to do some checking. Will update if I find something

Comment: Could you please provide the exact kernel version?

Comment: I was using 3.8.0-29-generic when it occurred yesterday, and switching back to 3.8.0-27 gave me the screen back. In fact, it was back even when rebooting again to 3.8.0-29 in the evening, and I've had no further problems so far.

Comment: Please consider integrating the information given to your answer.